# How sync C# RSACryptoServiceProvider with C++ cryptoapi

Tags: c#, c++, rsa, cryptoapi

1. crypt bytes in c++
2. load encrypted bytes to c# app and decrypt
3. i get exceptions with text "The parameter is incorrect."

How fix this?

My C# code:

```
 public static byte[] RSA_Decrypt(byte[] inputData, byte[] privateKey)
        {
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
            {
                rsa.ImportCspBlob(privateKey);

               return rsa.Decrypt(inputData, false);
```

My c++ code:

```
                            do
                            {
                                bReturn = CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_SILENT);

                                bReturn = CryptImportKey(hCryptProv,vecPublicKey.data(), vecPublicKey.size(), NULL, 0, &hCryptKey);




                                std::vector<unsigned char> vecBlock(2048), vecResult;

                                DWORD dwRead = 3;

                                    bReturn = CryptEncrypt(hCryptKey, NULL, TRUE, 0, (BYTE*)vecBlock.data(), &dwRead, vecBlock.size());

                                    vecResult.insert(vecResult.end(), vecBlock.begin(), vecBlock.begin() + dwRead);

                            } while (FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your C++ code? Just looking at it I can see you're not using "CryptEncrypt" correctly. With an RSA key of 2048 bits your encrypted output will always be 256 bytes long.

I don't know why you set the value of "DWORD dwRead = 3;" but even if you only want to encrypt 3 bytes, the output of encryption will have 256 bytes in the case of RSA encryption!

In your code, the value of "bReturn" will most likely be false after the call to "CryptEncrypt", meaning it has failed.

Also the calls to "CryptAcquireContext" and "CryptImportKey" should not be inside a "while" loop. They only need to be called once...

You may want to use another encryption algorithm if you need to encrypt large amounts of data. Try looking into AES instead.